# Sql building's entry and exit records

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.5

From the following table:

```
timestamp         inout  Name
2018-04-01 14:00    0    Tom
2018-04-02 06:00    1    Tom
2018-04-02 14:00    0    Tom
2018-04-03 06:00    1    Tom
2018-04-01 22:00    0    Rob
2018-04-02 14:00    1    Rob
2018-04-02 22:00    0    Rob
2018-04-03 13:00    1    Rob
2018-04-01 12:55    0    John
2018-04-02 06:05    1    John
2018-04-03 06:10    1    John
2018-04-01 14:05    0    Anna
2018-04-02 14:10    0    Anna
2018-04-02 14:15    1    Anna
2018-04-02 14:20    0    Anna
2018-04-03 14:05    0    Anna
2018-04-01 22:00    1    Mary
2018-04-02 06:00    0    Mary
2018-04-02 22:00    1    Mary
2018-04-03 06:00    0    Mary
```

*where 1=in 0=out*
I need to collect data of **"entry and exit records for 2018-04-02"** and present it in table like this:

```
d1-in-timestamp   d0-out-timestamp  Name
2018-04-02 07:00  2018-04-02 15:00  Tom
2018-04-02 14:00  2018-04-02 22:00  Rob
2018-04-02 06:05  -                 John
-                 2018-04-02 14:10  Anna
2018-04-02 14:15  2018-04-02 14:20  Anna
2018-04-02 00:00  2018-04-02 06:00  Mary
2018-04-02 22:00  2018-04-02 00:00  Mary
```

**In a perfect world**
Tom enters once to the building by passing "DOOR" and  leaves through the "DOOR" once. Tom is perfect! Be like Tom! :)
Rob is perfect too, but he is sleepyhead, so he comes to afternoon shift. :P
Anna comes to work with Tom. Tom keeps "DOOR" open for her, so theres no records about her entry. Moreover she keeps comming back 'cos she forgot something.
John is dodger! He comes to work late, so he should work it out, but he always slips with someone else through "DOOR" when other person leaves.
And at last Marry. She is on night shift, so she needs to be seen in a table in two records splitting a day.

**Is there possible to get such result in one table by one SQL query?**

So far I manage sql query like this:

```
select timestamp as d1, (select timestamp from DOOR where timestamp>m1.timestamp and inout=0 and name=m1.name) as d0, name from DOOR as m1 where substring(timestamp,1,10)='2018-04-02' and inout=1 order by name, timestamp
```

Query works for peole from "perfect world" (Tom & Rob) and more/less for John.
Unfortunatelly query does not work for Anna and Marry.

PS: Sorry for my english

Comment: This is a very hard task, because of the imperfections in the data.  MySQL is not a particularly powerful database.  I would be surprised if anyone were able to produce a comprehensive answer.

Comment: If Tom's first entry was an out, what assumptions could we make?

Comment: As an aside inout is a reserved word in MySQL (I've no idea why)

Comment: @Strawberry . . . `inout` is a type of parameter in a stored procedure.

Comment: Also, it's very hard to see how the data set relates to the result set.

Comment: Guys, about "inout" - this is only an example. Source table has less intuitive column names so I've hanged it for better example.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough one, but I figured out a query to do this. It uses some joins, subqueries and a union but produces the output you want. I started with @RajatJaiswals fiddle but created a completely new query.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    IF(inA.timestamp < '2018-04-02', '2018-04-02 00:00:00', inA.timestamp) AS `d1-in-timestamp`, 
    IFNULL(IF(outA.timestamp > '2018-04-02 23:59:59', CAST(DATE_ADD('2018-04-02', INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS DATETIME), outA.timestamp), '-') AS `d0-out-timestamp`, 
    inA.name AS `Name`
  FROM 
    attendance AS inA
    LEFT JOIN attendance AS outA ON (
      inA.name = outA.name 
      AND outA.inout = 0
      AND inA.timestamp < outA.timestamp
      AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT betweenA.name 
        FROM attendance AS betweenA
        WHERE 
          betweenA.name = inA.name
          AND betweenA.timestamp > inA.timestamp
          AND betweenA.timestamp < outA.timestamp
      )
    )
  WHERE 
    inA.inout = 1 
    AND (
      CAST(inA.timestamp AS DATE) = '2018-04-02' 
      OR CAST(outA.timestamp AS DATE) = '2018-04-02'
    )

  UNION

  SELECT 
    '-' AS `d1-in-timestamp`, 
    IF(outA.timestamp > '2018-04-02 23:59:59', CAST(DATE_ADD('2018-04-02', INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS DATETIME), outA.timestamp) AS `d0-out-timestamp`, 
    outA.name AS `Name`
  FROM
    attendance AS outA
    LEFT JOIN attendance AS inA ON (
      inA.name = outA.name 
      AND inA.inout = 1
      AND inA.timestamp < outA.timestamp
      AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT betweenA.name 
        FROM attendance AS betweenA
        WHERE 
          betweenA.name = inA.name
          AND betweenA.timestamp > inA.timestamp
          AND betweenA.timestamp < outA.timestamp
      )
    )
  WHERE 
    outA.inout = 0
    AND  CAST(outA.timestamp AS DATE) = '2018-04-02'
    AND inA.name IS NULL
) AS a
ORDER BY `Name`, `d1-in-timestamp`
```

This is a complicated query and may look daunting at first, but I try to break it up into small parts to explain what it does:

The outer `SELECT` is just to enable sorting over the complete result. This is required because of the `UNION` statement.

- The first inner `SELECT` clause just handles some output conversions

  - `IF(inA.timestamp < '2018-04-02', '2018-04-02 00:00:00', inA.timestamp)` is just for formatting and replaces timestamps from the day before with 00:00 of the day in question
  - `IFNULL(IF(outA.timestamp > '2018-04-02 23:59:59', CAST(DATE_ADD('2018-04-02', INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS DATETIME), outA.timestamp), '-')` is again for formatting, but does two things: replace null with `-` if the person didn't leave the building and replace timestamps of the day after with 00:00 of the day after
- In the `FROM` clause I use a `JOIN` to join together records of entering the building (`inA`) with records of leaving the building (`outA`). The interesting part is the `ON` clause:

  - I use the `name` column for joining only records of the same person
  - `outA` table should only look at people leaving (`inout = 0`)
  - `inA.timestamp < outA.timestamp` if the person did not enter before leaving these two entries shouldn't be joined together
  - There should not be any records of activity between the two records being joined. This is handled by the `NOT EXISTS` subquery. It searches for any record that

    - belongs to the same person (`betweenA.name = inA.name`)
    - happened after the `inA` record in question
    - happened before the `outA` record in question

    If any such record exists, the `NOT EXISTS` clause evaluates as false and the records are not joined. That way only subsequent in and out entries are joined together.
- The `WHERE` clause is simple:

  - Make sure only persons entering the building are selected from `inA`
  - At least one of the entries must be from the desired date (`CAST(inA.timestamp AS DATE)` converts the timestamp to a date thus removing the time part and makes comparison simple)

This selects all the records in which the person entering the building was recorded. We now still miss the case of Anna who was not recorded entering the building. That is where the `UNION` comes into place and adds this information to the result.

- The `SELECT` again is just output logic:

  - We have no record of the person entering, therefore there will never be a timestamp. Just return '-' for entry time
  - The logic for handling leaving timestamp is the same as above
- This time we start from leaving records and join the entering records to them. The `ON` clause does the following:

  - Use `name` to join only records of one person
  - `outA.inout = 1` as the join table should only use records of entering
  - the record of entering should happen before the building was left (`inA.timestamp < outA.timestamp`)
  - As above there may not be any other records between
- The `WHERE` clause does some important restrictions again:

  - `outA.inout = 0` as we need the table restricted to records of leaving the building
  - `CAST(outA.timestamp AS DATE) = '2018-04-02'` this time only checking the date of `outA` as there is no record of entering.
  - Only use results where there was no record of entering found (i.e. where there was no record found to join). This is the case if `inA.name IS NULL`

The last thing is the `ORDER BY` clause which should be self explanatory.

#### Output:

```
|     d1-in-timestamp |    d0-out-timestamp | Name |
|---------------------|---------------------|------|
|                   - | 2018-04-02 14:10:00 | Anna |
| 2018-04-02 14:15:00 | 2018-04-02 14:20:00 | Anna |
| 2018-04-02 06:05:00 |                   - | John |
| 2018-04-02 00:00:00 | 2018-04-02 06:00:00 | Mary |
| 2018-04-02 22:00:00 | 2018-04-03 00:00:00 | Mary |
| 2018-04-02 14:00:00 | 2018-04-02 22:00:00 |  Rob |
| 2018-04-02 06:00:00 | 2018-04-02 14:00:00 |  Tom |
```

You can try it in the following SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e618bb/7/0

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.Name,t1.TimeStamp asintime,t.timestamp as outtime
FROM tmpAttendance t
LEFT OUTER JOIN tmpAttendance t1 ON t.Name = t1.Name 
                 AND t1.inout = 1
                 AND CAST(t.timestamp AS DATE) =  CAST(t1.timestamp AS DATE)
 WHERE t.inout = 0
 ORDER BY t.Name ,t1.TimeStamp
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df678/5

Comment: Anna appears to have left before she arrived.

Answer (score 0):

Just one simple addition: Add a row for Mary with max time (2018-04-02 23:59) 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb41b1/6
And then you can use the logic below:

```
  select a.name,
    case when a.name != 'Mary' and (b.out_time is null or a.in_time <= b.out_time) then a.in_time
         when a.name != 'Mary' and b.out_time is not null and a.in_time > b.out_time then null
         when a.name = 'Mary' and  a.in_time > b.out_time then '2018-04-02 00:00:00'
         else a.in_time
    end as in_time,
    b.out_time     
    from
    (select name,time1 as in_time  from have1
    where inout1 = 1 and (substring(time1,1,10)='2018-04-02')) a
    left join
    (select name,time1 as out_time  from have1
    where inout1 = 0 and (substring(time1,1,10)='2018-04-02')) b
    on a.name = b.name
```

**Output:**

```
name    in_time                 out_time
Tom     2018-04-02 06:00:00  2018-04-02 14:00:00
Rob     2018-04-02 14:00:00  2018-04-02 22:00:00
John    2018-04-02 06:05:00  (null)
Anna    (null)               2018-04-02 14:10:00
Anna    2018-04-02 14:15:00  2018-04-02 14:20:00
Mary    2018-04-02 00:00:00  2018-04-02 06:00:00
Mary    2018-04-02 22:00:00  2018-04-02 23:59:59
```

Let me know in case any clarification is required.

Comment: Yes. Because there is no set rule to define whether the person is from night shift or not. Also, you didn't mention you have more people therefore The question was solved as per the requirement

Answer (score 0):

**Mary and the other night shifters**

First let's talk about Mary and other night shifters. We can find their in stamps, when we filter all in stamps where:

- No out stamp at the same day exists, that is after the in stamp.
- But an out stamp on the next day exists, and no in stamp on that next day exists that is before that out stamp.

For the out stamp, we use 00:00 hour of the next day of the in stamp.

```
SELECT d.`timestamp` `timestamp_in`,
       timestampadd(second, -1 * second(d.`timestamp`), timestampadd(minute, -1 * minute(d.`timestamp`), timestampadd(hour, -1 * hour(d.`timestamp`), timestampadd(day, 1, (d.`timestamp`))))) `timestamp_out`,
       d.`name`
       FROM `door` d
       WHERE d.`inout` = 1
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM `door` di
                                    WHERE di.`name` = d.`name`
                                          AND di.`inout` = 0
                                          AND di.`timestamp` > d.`timestamp`
                                          AND date(di.`timestamp`) = date(d.`timestamp`))
             AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM `door` di
                                WHERE di.`name` = d.`name`
                                      AND di.`inout` = 0
                                      AND date(di.`timestamp`) = date_add(date(d.`timestamp`), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                                      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                             FROM `door` dii
                                                             WHERE dii.`name` = di.`name`
                                                                   AND date(dii.`timestamp`) = date_add(date(d.`timestamp`), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                                                                   AND dii.`timestamp` < di.`timestamp`
                                                                   AND dii.`inout` = 1))
```

To get the out stamps of the night shifters, we can use the same logic but switch everything around:

- `>` becomes `<` in date comparisons and vice versa.
- Where there is a `0` for a stamp out make it a `1` for a stamp in and vice versa.
- Instead of the next day, compare to the previous day.

For the in stamp we use 00:00 hours of the day of the out stamp.

If we `UNION ALL` both queries, we get the part for the night shifters.

**The rest of the gang aka the day shifters**

Getting the in stamps for the day shifters is easy now. We simply need to negate the condition we used to find the night shifters. To get the in stamps:

```
SELECT d.`timestamp`,
       d.`name`
       FROM `door` d
       WHERE d.`inout` = 1
             AND (EXISTS (SELECT *
                                 FROM `door` di
                                 WHERE di.`name` = d.`name`
                                       AND di.`inout` = 0
                                       AND di.`timestamp` > d.`timestamp`
                                       AND date(di.`timestamp`) = date(d.`timestamp`))
                   OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                         FROM `door` di
                                         WHERE di.`name` = d.`name`
                                               AND di.`inout` = 0
                                               AND date(di.`timestamp`) = date_add(date(d.`timestamp`), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                                               AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                                      FROM `door` dii
                                                                      WHERE dii.`name` = di.`name`
                                                                            AND date(dii.`timestamp`) = date_add(date(d.`timestamp`), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                                                                            AND dii.`timestamp` < di.`timestamp`
                                                                            AND dii.`inout` = 1)))
```

For the out stamps we can again switch things around, `>` becomes `<`, etc., like above.

Of course here we cannot generate the in stamps for the out stamps and vice versa. We'd have to `FULL OUTER JOIN` the in stamps and the out stamps of the day shifters. But MySQL at least in lower versions does not support this operation. So we do by `UNION`ing two `LEFT JOIN`, reversing the roles in the second `LEFT JOIN` compared to the first.

**Putting it all together**

Now we can simply `UNION ALL` the night shifters and the day shifters to get the complete result for all days. And we can `SELECT FROM` that, to get the result for a specific day:

```
SELECT coalesce(x.`timestamp_in`, '-') `d1-in-timestamp`,
       coalesce(x.`timestamp_out`, '-') `d0-out-timestamp`,
       x.`name`
       FROM (SELECT r.`timestamp` `timestamp_in`,
                    s.`timestamp` `timestamp_out`,
                    r.`name`
                    FROM (SELECT d.`timestamp`,
                                 d.`name`
                                 FROM `door` d
                                 WHERE d.`inout` = 1
                                       AND (EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                           FROM `door` di
                                                           WHERE di.`name` = d.`name`
                                                                 AND di.`inout` = 0
                                                                 AND di.`timestamp` > d.`timestamp`
                                                                 AND date(di.`timestamp`) = date(d.`timestamp`))
                                             OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                                   FROM `door` di
                                                                   WHERE di.`name` = d.`name`
                                                                         AND di.`inout` = 0
                                                                         AND date(di.`timestamp`) = date_add(date(d.`timestamp`), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                                                                         AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                                                                FROM `door` dii
                                                                                                WHERE dii.`name` = di.`name`
                                                                                                      AND date(dii.`timestamp`) = date_add(date(d.`timestamp`), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                                                                                                      AND dii.`timestamp` < di.`timestamp`
                                                                                                      AND dii.`inout` = 1)))) r
                         LEFT JOIN (SELECT d.`timestamp`,
                                           d.`name`
                                           FROM `door` d
                                           WHERE d.`inout` = 0
                                                 AND (EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                                     FROM `door` di
                                                                     WHERE di.`name` = d.`name`
                                                                           AND di.`inout` = 1
                                                                           AND di.`timestamp` < d.`timestamp`
                                                                           AND date(di.`timestamp`) = date(d.`timestamp`))
                                                       OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                                             FROM `door` di
                                                                             WHERE di.`name` = d.`name`
                                                                                   AND di.`inout` = 1
                                                                                   AND date(di.`timestamp`) = date_add(date(d.`timestamp`), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
                                                                                   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                                                                          FROM `door` dii
                                                                                                          WHERE dii.`name` = di.`name`
                                                                                                                AND date(dii.`timestamp`) = date_add(date(d.`timestamp`), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
                                                                                                                AND dii.`timestamp` > di.`timestamp`
                                                                                                                AND dii.`inout` = 0)))) s
                                   ON s.`name` = r.`name`
                                      AND date(s.`timestamp`) = date(r.`timestamp`)
                                      AND s.`timestamp` > r.`timestamp`
             UNION
             SELECT u.`timestamp` `timestamp_in`,
                    t.`timestamp` `timestamp_out`,
                    t.`name`
                    FROM (SELECT d.`timestamp`,
                                 d.`name`
                                 FROM `door` d
                                 WHERE d.`inout` = 0
                                       AND (EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                           FROM `door` di
                                                           WHERE di.`name` = d.`name`
                                                                 AND di.`inout` = 1
                                                                 AND di.`timestamp` < d.`timestamp`
                                                                 AND date(di.`timestamp`) = date(d.`timestamp`))
                                             OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                                   FROM `door` di
                                                                   WHERE di.`name` = d.`name`
                                                                         AND di.`inout` = 1
                                                                         AND date(di.`timestamp`) = date_add(date(d.`timestamp`), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
                                                                         AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                                                                FROM `door` dii
                                                                                                WHERE dii.`name` = di.`name`
                                                                                                      AND date(dii.`timestamp`) = date_add(date(d.`timestamp`), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
                                                                                                      AND dii.`timestamp` > di.`timestamp`
                                                                                                      AND dii.`inout` = 0)))) t
                         LEFT JOIN (SELECT d.`timestamp`,
                                           d.`name`
                                           FROM `door` d
                                           WHERE d.`inout` = 1
                                                 AND (EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                                     FROM `door` di
                                                                     WHERE di.`name` = d.`name`
                                                                           AND di.`inout` = 0
                                                                           AND di.`timestamp` > d.`timestamp`
                                                                           AND date(di.`timestamp`) = date(d.`timestamp`))
                                                       OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                                             FROM `door` di
                                                                             WHERE di.`name` = d.`name`
                                                                                   AND di.`inout` = 0
                                                                                   AND date(di.`timestamp`) = date_add(date(d.`timestamp`), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                                                                                   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                                                                          FROM `door` dii
                                                                                                          WHERE dii.`name` = di.`name`
                                                                                                                AND date(dii.`timestamp`) = date_add(date(d.`timestamp`), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                                                                                                                AND dii.`timestamp` < di.`timestamp`
                                                                                                                AND dii.`inout` = 1)))) u
                                   ON u.`name` = t.`name`
                                      AND date(u.`timestamp`) = date(t.`timestamp`)
                                      AND u.`timestamp` < t.`timestamp`
             UNION
             SELECT d.`timestamp` `timestamp_in`,
                    timestampadd(second, -1 * second(d.`timestamp`), timestampadd(minute, -1 * minute(d.`timestamp`), timestampadd(hour, -1 * hour(d.`timestamp`), timestampadd(day, 1, (d.`timestamp`))))) `timestamp_out`,
                    d.`name`
                    FROM `door` d
                    WHERE d.`inout` = 1
                          AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                 FROM `door` di
                                                 WHERE di.`name` = d.`name`
                                                       AND di.`inout` = 0
                                                       AND di.`timestamp` > d.`timestamp`
                                                       AND date(di.`timestamp`) = date(d.`timestamp`))
                          AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                                             FROM `door` di
                                             WHERE di.`name` = d.`name`
                                                   AND di.`inout` = 0
                                                   AND date(di.`timestamp`) = date_add(date(d.`timestamp`), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                                                   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                                          FROM `door` dii
                                                                          WHERE dii.`name` = di.`name`
                                                                                AND date(dii.`timestamp`) = date_add(date(d.`timestamp`), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                                                                                AND dii.`timestamp` < di.`timestamp`
                                                                                AND dii.`inout` = 1))
             UNION ALL
             SELECT timestampadd(second, -1 * second(d.`timestamp`), timestampadd(minute, -1 * minute(d.`timestamp`), timestampadd(hour, -1 * hour(d.`timestamp`), d.`timestamp`))) `timestamp_in`,
                    d.`timestamp` `timestamp_out`,
                    d.`name`
                    FROM `door` d
                    WHERE d.`inout` = 0
                          AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                 FROM `door` di
                                                 WHERE di.`name` = d.`name`
                                                       AND di.`inout` = 1
                                                       AND di.`timestamp` < d.`timestamp`
                                                       AND date(di.`timestamp`) = date(d.`timestamp`))
                          AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                                             FROM `door` di
                                             WHERE di.`name` = d.`name`
                                                   AND di.`inout` = 1
                                                   AND date(di.`timestamp`) = date_add(date(d.`timestamp`), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
                                                   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                                          FROM `door` dii
                                                                          WHERE dii.`name` = di.`name`
                                                                                AND date(dii.`timestamp`) = date_add(date(d.`timestamp`), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
                                                                                AND dii.`timestamp` > di.`timestamp`
                                                                                AND dii.`inout` = 0))) x
       WHERE date(x.`timestamp_in`) = '2018-04-02'
              OR date(x.`timestamp_out`) = '2018-04-02'
       ORDER BY x.`name`,
                x.`timestamp_in`;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=beff8668d3e2bac958896d51c8135a88)

Comment: Your result contains a row for Mary which shouldn't be there: 2018-04-01 22:00:00 - 2018-04-02 00:00:00

Comment: @LienhartWoitok: I know thta. But, well, the OP is a little inconsistent there. It requests "entry and exit records for 2018-04-02" and that record for Mary you mention is an exit record at 2018-04-02. The sample result also has the last entry for Mary wrong, her timestamps are all on the same day but that makes no sense (she'd left before she came). And Tom's records are an hour off. So I felt, I'd rather go with the logical description the OP gave, than with the sample result they might have had difficulties to compose with.